# How can I avoid duplication of conditions that apply to multiple steps in my Jenkinsfile pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Currently I have a Jenkinsfile that looks like the following :

```
stage('A'){
  agent{docker{image A}}
  when{branch = 'master'}
  step{do blah} 
}    
stage('B'){
  when{branch = 'master'}
  agent{docker{image B}}
  step{do blah} 
}
```

Concern is that this condition is duplicated all over the place and I'd like to extract it - but fail to identify the correct syntax if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use env variable at first (to set the condition):
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#setting-environment-variables-dynamically .

then you can use the environment `when`: 
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions

> Execute the stage when the specified environment variable is set to
>   the given value, for example:

```
when { environment name: 'DEPLOY_TO', value: 'production' }
```